# Warum gibt es hier ein "auf"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Als die drei Forscher die ersten zehn Millionen Primzahlen **auf** 
>    *diese Eigenschaften* **hin** prüften, stellten sie fest, dass..

Das ist nicht das erste Mal, dass ich etwas sowieso sehe.. Z. B habe ich die Ausdrücke wie **auf Anfrage**, **auf Vorschlag hin** und...gesehen.

1)Was ist die Grammatik und ich möchte auch wissen, was hier *hin* macht?

2)Wäre es möglich, "*mit diesen Eigenschaften*" zu benutzen mit derselben Bedeutung in diesem Text?

Comment: compare "check *up* [on]". Potentially fossilized syntagma. Another example for my suspicion that Laryngeals were not completely lost, cf. the PIE root for "in"; cp. *eingehend prüfen*, *in-vestigate*, *hinterher/nach-gehen*; cp. *auf* with *up*, Nl. *ob*, thus Ger. *ob* "whether, if, against", archaic "Ob der Lage" (i.e. *wegen*, meiner bescheidenen Lesart nach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"im Hinblick auf etwas" kann synonym für "auf etwas hin" verwendet werden. Dies dient bei "prüfen" dazu, das Prüfziel explizit herauszustellen.

Im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/pr%C3%BCfen) steht als Bedeutung für "prüfen"

> 1) a) α) etw., jmdn. im Hinblick auf etw. untersuchen
>
> 1) a) β) ⟨etw. (auf etw.) prüfen⟩im Hinblick auf seine vorgeschriebenen Eigenschaften
>
> 1) a) γ) ⟨etw. (auf etw.) prüfen⟩im Hinblick auf eine bestimmte Eigenschaft

Beim DWDS-Eintrag für "prüfen" fehlt im Gegensatz zum [Duden-Eintrag](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/pruefen) ein Beispiel mit "hin", der [separate DWDS-Eintrag](https://www.dwds.de/wb/hin) für "hin" sagt

> in der ersten Zeile Wortbildung: mit ›hin‹ als Letztglied: ↗dahin

zum gebrachten Beispiel passend:

> im Eintrag 2.g):  kausal: ⟨auf ... hin⟩aufgrund

**zur Frage 1)**

Die DWDS-Einträge sollten deutlich machen, dass es sehr vielfältige Konstruktionen gibt. Die größeren Blöcke sind

> 1) "räumlich, bezeichnet die Richtung vom Sprecher weg auf einen Zielpunkt zu"
>
> und 4) "nach adverbialer Bestimmung, bekräftigt häufig ein Geschehen oder einen anhaltenden Zustand"

**zur Frage 2)**

- Als die drei Forscher die ersten zehn Millionen Primzahlen auf diese Eigenschaften hin prüften, stellten sie fest, dass..

vs.

- Als die drei Forscher die ersten zehn Millionen Primzahlen mit diesen Eigenschaften prüften, stellten sie fest, dass..

Ist etwas unterschiedliches:

- im ersten Fall werden die Primzahlen untersucht, ob sie eine bestimmte Eigenschaft haben und wie diese ausgeprägt ist - es ist zur Überprüfung unklar, ob sie die Eigenschaften haben und es ist wichtig, wie sie ausgeprägt sind, das ist das Untersuchungsziel
- im zweiten Fall werden die Primzahlen untersucht, die gewisse Eigenschaften haben - es ist zur Überprüfung Vorraussetzung, dass sie die Eigenschaften haben und es ist egal, wie sie ausgeprägt sind, das Untersuchungsziel ist ein anderes

Answer (score 3):

Zu 2) Nein, das ist etwas anderes. Die Forscher prüften die ersten 10 Millionen Primzahlen, ob sie irgendwelche Eigenschaften haben. In Deiner Formulierung wäre nichts zu prüfen gewesen, weil man nur Zahlen mit diesen Eigenschaften hat.

Zu 1) *Auf etwas hin prüfen* ist eine feste Wendung. Man guckt sich etwas an und schaut, ob es eine bestimmte Eigenschaft hat. In sofern ist das ein Richtungsangabe: das Untersuchte kann noch viele weitere Eigenschaften haben, die einen gerade nicht interessieren

Comment: 2) ist evtl unglücklich formuliert, denn: "Als die drei Forscher die ersten zehn Millionen Primzahlen mit diesen Eigenschaften prüften, stellten sie fest, dass [nur die erste auf der Ziffer 2 endete.]" - Formulierung ist ja möglich, hat aber andere Bedeutung.